# A prize in 10 boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, paradoxes

I am trying to make sense out of this experiment :

**There is a prize randomly put in one of 10 boxes. I am supposed to guess the box in which the prize lies.**

**Q1:** What is the sample space here ?
Is it labels of the box being guessed by me at every attempt? Example: {*1, 2, 3 .. 10*}
Or is it the nth attempt that I am currently at? {*Prize found in 1st attempt, Prize found in 2nd attempt ... , Prize found in 10th attempt*}

**Q2:** Why I am not getting Probability $1$ in total ?
The probabilities of me able to find the prize in $i^{th}$ attempt comes out to be $\frac{1}{10}$ for any attempt.

Example: Prize to be found in 3rd attempt = $\frac{9}{10}*\frac{8}{9}*\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{10}$

However, If I am not able to find the prize till $9^{th}$ box, I will always be able to tell the prize as the $10^{th}$ box with certainty. I am not sure how will the probabilities add upto $1$ in this case.

What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: The probability that you find the prize on the 10th attempt *given that you did not find it on any of the first 9 attempts* is 1, but the unconditional probability that you find it on the 10th attempt is $\frac1{10}$.

Comment: Keep applying the same formula and you will see how it works out.

Comment: You focus on 10th try , but you have same problem at 9th try (or at any try) ; at 9th try, you have 50% chance to find the correct box ; but it is not 50% of total universe, it is 50% of a partiel universe, and this universe is : 'not finding the prize during the 8 first trys' ; it is 50% of 20%.

Comment: @Lourrran - Oh yes. It makes so much sense. In the 10th attempt, its 100% of 10% in the partial universe. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Lourrran - Can you please help me understand how you would think of a sample space and outcomes (or events) in this experiment?

Comment: When you deduce probability that you are counting as $1/10$ is a way of asking what Is the probability of finding the prize in $10th$ box if I don't know anything at all about any other boxes, While when you eventually open boxes one by one, what you are doing is increasing the information known to you, The question will then be, What is probability of getting a prize in $10th$ box given/known that first $n$ out of $10$ didn't have it, The difference is now you have extra information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1 :** The Sample Space can be "modeled" in various equivalent ways.
It is covering the ways the Prize is put.
One way to "model" that is with tuples : the Sample Space will then be :
$(1,0,0,0,\cdots)$ , $(0,1,0,0,\cdots)$ , $(0,0,1,0,\cdots)$ , ETC
where there are $10$ elements (Boxes) in the tuple & $9$ elements are $0$ (no Prize) with a Single element having $1$ (Contains Prize).
Sample space will have $10$ such tuples. All are Equally likely.

Your attempts are not the Sample Space in this model. Your attempts will be the Experimental Process & the outcomes & the history of the Experiment.

**Q2 :** When you start the Experiment , you know the Prize is there , hence you have Probability $1=100\%$ to "find" it.
What you do not know is which Box has it.
Probability that the Box you select has it is $1/10=10\%$.

Conditionally , "if" that selected Box does not have it , the Probability that the other $9$  Boxes have it is ..... $1=100%$ !!

When you have eliminated $1$ Box , you can now make your second selection.
Probability that the new Box you select has it is $1/9$.
With the Experimental Process , getting to the Eliminated State & getting the Prize is $9/10 \times 1/9 = 1/10$

With the Experimental Process , getting to the Eliminated State & then Eliminating 1 more Box is $9/10 \times 8/9 = 8/10$

When you have Eliminated $2$ Boxes , you can now make your third selection.
Probability that the new Box you select has it is $1/8$.
With the Experimental Process , getting to that State & getting the Prize is $8/10 \times 1/8 = 1/10$

With the Experimental Process , getting to that State & then Eliminating $1$ more Box is $8/10 \times 7/8 = 7/10$

Continuing this way , we can see that Probability will always make up $1$ , till the END State.

Consider the Last Box :
You have Eliminated $9$ Boxes , which will have Probability $9/10 \times 8/9 \times 7/8 \times \cdots \times 1/2 = 1/10$
When you check the Last Box , you will "find" the Prize with Probability $1$.
Over-all Probability , to get to that END State & then "find" the Prize , is $1/10 \times 1 = 1/10$

**Nothing to worry over !!**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prem for your thoughtful answer. I believe I was confusing the concept of Experiment and Sample Space. I will read up more on this. Also, the way to approach this in the way of "probability to get to that state * probability of finding the prize in that state" is something that I had not thought of.

Comment: Nice to know that this Answer was useful , @Abhishek , you should also check out "Conditional Probability" which will cover that Concept with more generality.